How to Connect an Existing SQLite Database with Custom Primary Keys to Django?
I am developing a web application in Python Django for managing vehicle parts. I have already designed the database in SQLite3 with multiple tables and pre-populated data (without using Django). Each table has its own primary key that is different from the others. For example:

The Price table uses a primary key of the form Year+Counter on 8 positions.
The Article table has a primary key that is a 10-character string.

I created these keys using triggers and other custom logic.
Now, I want to connect this existing SQLite database to Django. However, I am facing issues because Django expects its own primary key logic. This doesn't suit my needs.

Is there a way to connect my existing SQLite database with its custom primary keys to Django?
If not, are there other Python frameworks that might better support my database structure and logic?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Normally custom primary keys are not a problem, as long as these are not composite primary keys.

You justadd the custom primary key to your model:
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    # …
you can also give the field a different name, or work with the db_column=… [Django-doc] to specify the name of the column.
Django can use a lot of types as primary key, but has no (native) support for composite primary keys: a primary key that is the combination of two other fields. So the primary key needs to be one column in the database. The main problem with such composite primary key would ge foreign keys that refer to it, forms, etc.
